# How to get row index of pandas dataframe containing specific values from two columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I get a row index using two column conditions?

For example if I have a dataframe that looks like:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wkTZ.png)

If I specify that I want the row where "Pocket" is 0 and "Denim" is 1, I want the integer "1" returned, as 1 is the row index that satisfies these two column conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), but for general solution use `next` for return first matched row index and if not exist values (mask return all `False` values) is used default parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['Jeans','Shorts','Jeans'],
                   'Pocket':[1,0,1],
                   'Denim':[0,1,1]}, index=[4,8,10])

print (df)
   Product  Pocket  Denim
4    Jeans       1      0
8   Shorts       0      1
10   Jeans       1      1

mask = (df["Pocket"] == 0) & (df["Denim"] == 1)
a = next(iter(df[mask].index), 'not exist')
print (a)
8

mask = (df["Pocket"] == 0) & (df["Denim"] == 0)
a = next(iter(df[mask].index), 'not exist')
print (a)
not exist
```